# Directory.EnumerateFiles - Get Files which start with certain number and greater than that same number?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get list of files which starts with "6" and greater than this number. I have following list of files in a folder. In case of failure of certain file consider **6_q.sql** I want to begin with that file and proceed ahead in ascending order.

```
1_q.sql
2_q.sql
6_q.sql
7_q.sql
8_q.sql
```

This is my current code, however I used StartsWith and it only takes **6_q.sql** file not rest **7_q.sql** and **8_q.sql** in this case.

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql")
           .Where(filename => Path.GetFileName(filename).StartsWith("6"))
           .OrderBy(filename => filename);
```

May I know what can I use to take files starting with 6 and great then that in acending order?

Edit 1 - Filenames can have any characters after number like `11qq.sql`

Comment: Hint: presumably you would want to include "10_q.sql" as well, even though that comes lexicographically earlier. That suggests you should be writing some code to convert a filename to a number (potentially with a combination of string.Split and int.Parse). Your condition might be something like `.Where(filename => ParseLeadingNumber(filename) >= 6`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right. I was missing lexicographical order and 10_q.sql file came up which should not be the case it should start with 6_q.sql then 8,9,10_q.sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file order is not important for you, you can just order files by `filename` us [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql")
       .OrderBy(filename => filename)
       .SkipWhile(filename => Path.GetFileName(filename) != failedFileName)
       .Skip(1);
```

If ordering by number is important (and number at start of filename is always present) then you will need to parse that number, convert it to `int` and order by it:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^\d+");
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql")
       .Select(file => (n: int.Parse(reg.Match(Path.GetFileName(file)).Value), file))
       .Where(t => t.n > failedFileNumber)
       .OrderBy(t => t.n)
       .Select(t => t.file);
```

Comment: 1st solution is not applicable to me as order of file by number in ascending order is important. Using 2nd solution produces error `Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported`. Looks like this works on above .Net Framework 4.7.

Comment: @SQLLearner you can change that to anonymous type `.Select(file => new{ n = int.Parse(reg.Match(Path.GetFileName(file)).Value), file})` or add [`System.ValueTuple` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"yourpath", "*.sql")
            .Where(filename => GetNumberPart(Path.GetFileName(filename)) >= 6)
            .Select(Path.GetFileName);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int GetNumberPart(string value)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(value, @"^\d+").Value);
    }
```

Comment: That's not the case. File can start with any characters after number. There is no control over it.

Comment: I am using `EnumerateFiles` and getting exception `Input string was not in a correct format.'`. I tried this `var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql").Where(filename => GetNumberPart(Path.GetFileName(filename)) >= 6).OrderBy(filename => filename);`

Comment: I change the regex as my filename check is doing number check at the start. `return Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(value, @"^\d+").Value);`

Comment: I updated my answer with your codes and it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, write a small function to convert a file name to a number that can be compared. One way to do it:

```
int FileNumber(string input)
{
    string numericString = new string(input.Where( c => char.IsDigit(c) ).ToArray());
    bool ok = int.TryParse(numericString, out int result);
    if (ok) return result;
    return default(int);
}
```

Once you have that it's pretty easy:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql")
           .Where(filename => FileNumber(filename) >= 6 )
           .OrderBy(filename => filename);
```

If you're picky about the file order you may need something slightly more complex:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SQLScriptsFolderPath, "*.sql")
           .Select( x => new { FileName = x, FileNumber = FileNumber(x) })
           .Where( x => x.FileNumber >= 6 )
           .OrderBy( x => x.FileNumber );
           .Select( x => x.FileName )
```

Comment: Someonehow the `FileNumber` function did not work in my case.

Comment: @SQLLearner Can you be more specific?